# Was the Nimitz-class a predecessor of the Miranda-class?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

I recently saw a clip of Discovery and they showed the USS Europa:

[image]

While there are other shots of the ships from other angles, I noticed it looked very similar to another famous Star Trek ship:

[image]

I know from Memory Alpha that they called the Nimitz and Miranda classes, respectively.  Has there been any word from the staff of *Star Trek Discovery* that mentioned whether or not these two ships are related?

Comment: Well, all Starfleet ships are related.   One assumes that they are designed similarly because they are based on similar design goals.  What other answer would you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They may seem superficially similar from certain angles, largely as a result of the need to obey certain [Star Trek starship design rules](https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/design.htm#:%7E:text=He%20was%20nice%20enough%20to,fully%20visible%20from%20the%20front.), but they aren't nearly as closely matched as you might think.

Both have a "roll-bar" over the top but the Nimitz's is connected at the middle to the dish and has additional warp drives attached directly to it, as well as the upper drives connecting directly to the dish.

[image]

I've used the models [here](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/uss-europa-nimitz-class-cruiser-4e38742f1edf44d2bca3b293e9bcaa98) and [here](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/miranda-class-uss-reliant-ncc-1864-variant-250b036815f04e12afe83145cec30cfb) for reference, along with the original concept art from John Eaves (above).

[image]

[image]

It's not hard to see a common ancestor but you're basically looking at a case of "*How do we attach four nacelles to this dish and still have it look like a Starfleet wessel?*"